Undefined variable $recipient
In lime 33 in profile.blade.php:
Undefined variable $recipient
 <a href="{{ route('messages.send', $recipient->id) }}">Send Message</a>
I have the profile controller where:
public function showProfile()
    {
        $recipient = Auth::user(); // Get the authenticated user
        return view('profile', ['recipient' => $recipient]);
    }

I am trying to make messanger with two auntheficated users. That line 33 is in profile.blade.php, that adds a link to send.blade.php. Expected that "Send Message" button redirect me to the chat with the user which profile I was watching.
I aren't really sure which code I need to show, so ask me please if you need more details
I am dying doing this project >:(

Since the line you say is causing the error is not in the function you've posted I can only assume that $recipient is not actually defined in the scope where the error occurs.

Since you're just getting the id of the Authenticated user, you can just use Auth::user()->id instead of $recipient->id. But I question the logic... it sounds like the user is just trying to send a message to themself?
